# How to enable snapping when moving multiple objects in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

I have the following problem: I'm using Visio to design tiling patterns and have a problem when copying tile groups. I can make individual tiles snap together well (all my tiles are polygons drawn with the line tool with inward & outward connection points, DirA and DirB are then cleared in the ShapeSheet to prevent snap-rotation), but when I want to copy a group of tiles to another place in the pattern, it won't snap to other tiles, I have to drag each tile one by one.

If the tiles are of the same color and this group is common in the pattern, I can circumvent this by combining this group into a single tile and creating new connection points for it. I cannot combine tiles of different colors and grouping doesn't help at all.

Is there a feature of Visio I have missed (or is it present in a newer version than my 2007?) that will allow snapping when dragging multiple selected objects?